# Flutter Widget: Launching an app on tap of a device home screen's widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter project and I'm using the home_widget package (version 0.3.1) to create a home widget that is displayed on the home screen of the device.
I would like to know how to launch my app when the user taps on this widget from device's home screen.
Can someone provide me with guidance or code examples on how to achieve this using the `home_widget` package?

Comment: The default intent on widget is already set to open the app. You trying to do something extra?

Comment: I tried example of home_widget project but it did not works.

Comment: I've used the package (ver 0.3.0) for my project and It does works. Idk why you're facing this issue..